# Extending displays across HDMI and Thunderbolt 3

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I currently a Dell XPS15 and have extended the display to a separate monitor using the HDMI port and a VGA connector.

I want to extend my display to a second monitor. With the end result being that I have three separate displays I can use.

I've read some stuff about spiting VGA cables using something like DualHead2Go Digital SE (Open Box). I'm wondering however if I could just use my Thunderbolt 3 port to have the same effect?

Plan: To use both the HDMI port and the Thunderblot 3 port simultaneously to create three separate displays.